# Fill Numpy Array row wise

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I am experimenting with Numpy features and want to know if there is a way to achieve the desired behavior as explained.
Given a numpy array as shown below

```
array = np.array([[1,3,3],[6,7,6],[9,9,4]])
print(array)
```

Output from `print(array)`

```
[[1 3 3]
 [6 7 6]
 [9 9 4]]
```

I am getting the maximum in each row

```
max_array =  array.max(axis=1,keepdims=1)
print(max_array)
```

Output from `print(max_array)`

```
[[3]
 [7]
 [9]]
```

I am applying the mask on all the maximum elements in the array using the code below

```
masked_array = np.ma.masked_equal(array,max_array)
print(masked_array)
```

Output from print`(masked_array)`

```
[[1 -- --]
 [6 -- 6]
 [-- -- 4]]
```

Now that I have masked the array, I want to perform operation to the non-max elements in the array like multiplication by 3 as show in the code below

```
 mul_array= np.multiply(masked_array,3)
 print(mul_array)
```

Output from `print(mul_array)`

```
[[3 -- --]
 [18 -- 18]
 [-- -- 12]]
```

I want to insert the maximum elements in the max_array which were masked earlier in the same position in the mul_array, but I couldn't find anything to achieve the desired behavior. Below is my expected matrix. I wanted to ask if there are any Numpy operation to achieve the desired behavior

Desired output

```
[[3 3 3]
 [18 7 18]
 [9 9 12]]
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: @wwii thank you for recommending the resources. I have updated my post. Please let me know if there is still something missing that can be updated to meet the standard

Comment: `np.ma.masked_equal(a,b)` - what are `a` and `b`?

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. I forgot to replace the a and b with array and max_array. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,3,3],[6,7,6],[9,9,4]])
```

First find you max values

```
max_array =  a.max(axis=1,keepdims=True)

In [19]: max_array
Out[19]: 
array([[3],
       [7],
       [9]])
```

Then make a boolean array for all the values that are not

```
mask = (a != max_array)

In [20]: mask
Out[20]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Then use the mask to filter the assignment on the *left-hand-side* and for the operation on the *right-hand-side*.

```
a[mask] = a[mask] * 3

In [21]: a
Out[21]: 
array([[ 3,  3,  3],
       [18,  7, 18],
       [ 9,  9, 12]])
```

---

[Numpy Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

---

The same process with a masked array

```
b = np.array([[1,3,3],[6,7,6],[9,9,4]])
b_max =  b.max(axis=1,keepdims=True)
b_ma = np.ma.masked_equal(b,b_max)
q = b_ma * 3
b = q.data

# or
b_ma *= 3
b = b_ma.data
```

Those will result in `b` being a view of the data in `b_ma`.

```
In [80]: b.flags['OWNDATA']
Out[80]: False
```

If you don't want a view -

```
In [81]: b = b_ma.data.copy()

In [82]: b.flags['OWNDATA']
Out[82]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use `np.nan` instead of `--` and a flattened version of `B`:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, np.nan], [4, np.nan, 6], [7, 8, np.nan]])
B = np.array([[3], [5], [9]])
B = B.flatten()
```

So `B` is of the form `[3, 5, 9]` now. Then you can identify locations of cells with these `np.nan` and reassign them:

```
x, y = np.nonzero(np.isnan(A))
A[x,y] = B
```

Output:

```
>>> A
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])
```

Note that:

- type of `A` is `float` because of `np.nan`s were used before this
- change `np.nonzero` is a substitute for `np.where` in 1D cases
- You might like to work with `np.copy(A)` instead in order to avoid dynamical changes of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I changed the syntax so that all the arrays and values match numpy syntax. Then you create an array 'indexes' to store indexes where A array has null values. Create a C array which is a copy of A, and use the np.take function to fill in the null values with B values.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([ [1, 2, np.nan],
      [4, np.nan, 6],
      [7, 8, np.nan] ])
B = np.array([ [3],
      [5],
      [9] ,
     ])

indexes = np.where(np.isnan(A))

C = np.copy(A)

C[indexes] = np.take(B, indexes[0])

print(C)
```